# Where are laptop keyboard drivers found?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, keyboard, laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite Intel centrino duo laptop running ubuntu 12.04

What files are responsible for the keyboard working / Where are the keyboard drivers located?

Say hypothetically the caps lock light doesn't light up and pressing a key does nothing and I needed to install "drivers" to get it working... where would those drivers go?

/lib/modules ?
/proc ?
Where?

Comment: Although I can't answer the question, I'd like to point out that `/proc` is where all the information about the processes is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i've read you have 2 situations, where keyboard is handled by some kernel module, and if you install XORG server, for example, it can be also handled by it.

So with the kernel drivers, they should be in something like:

`/lib/modules/2.6.2x.xx/kernel/drivers/input/keyboard/`

For XORG:

`/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/kbd_drv.so`