# Keyboard not working/ kbd_drv.so missing

Tags: 12.04, drivers, xorg, keyboard

The keyboard stopped working on my Acer Aspire One running Ubuntu 12.04.

The keyoard doesn't work when the computer is booted (ie: I can't press F12 to change the boot order) amd it doesn't work when running Ubuntu 12.10 from a pendrive either. I'm currently using a USB keyboard.

The file [kbd_drv.so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179801/where-are-laptop-keyboard-drivers-found) seems to be missing but the following drivers are there.

```
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/ ls
evdev_drv.so mouse_drv.so synaptics_drv.so vmmouse_drv.so wacom_drv.so
```

How can I fix it/what could the problem be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The file `kbd_drv.so` has been superseded by `evdev_drv.so` for a while. You can still install it by installing the `xserver-xorg-input-kbdp` package:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-kbd
```

But that will most likely not fix anything. This seems like a hardware problem to me, since the keyboard won't work also for entering the boot setup, that has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Run this command from a terminal:

```
xev
```

Press some keys on your laptop keyboard. Does it react to keystrokes? Press some keys also on your USB keyboard for reference. It probably won't.

Remove the battery, unplug your laptop, wait some minutes and then plug all again. If the problem persists, I think your kaptop keyboard (probably some wiring) is broken.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've tried xev and it didn't react to any keystrokes from the laptop keyboard. I'll try unplugging everything, but I'm not expecting any miracles.