# How to connect a projector to my Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am wondering if someone knows how I can connect my laptop with ubuntu 12.04 to a projector. I tried all the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to <kbd>F10</kbd> is still not working.

This a dual boot : if I switch to windows it works perfectly but would not work with Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you need to download keyboard driver.

Comment: @AmirNoori err... keyboards... don't need drivers in Linux/Ubuntu...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/179801/where-are-laptop-keyboard-drivers-found

Comment: I had success by booting up with the projector already connected to the SVGA port.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't use booting. just go to *System Setting* > *Display*. Set on another display and `800x600` resolution and then press apply. no problem at all on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

Since the first time I use GNU/Linux. I always use [arandr](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/) when it comes to managing external screen.

arndr in action:
[image: arndr in action]

You can drag the external active screen atop your current screen, save the configuration, reload it in other session, or even change the screen resolution. Pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings->displays->detect displays.
there u can apply mirror desktop

Answer (score 1):

Go to system setting>display you find a checkbox for mirror displays but you must notice that there is a note that it is for limited resolution only therefor, for the same time change the resolution to 800*600 it will work in your laptop as well as on projector

Comment: If the projector doesn't work, how does this help?

Comment: you may see is there  a technical problem in it